# How do i replace WordPress page title with an image?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, parent-child

I am trying to replace the text on my WordPress site page titles with an image. I am working locally with a child theme. I need to also be able to target each page separately as the images will be different.

It currently looks like:
[image]

I want to design some custom titles in Photoshop and save them as Jpg/Png and then replace the text.

I think i have identified the right part of the CSS

```html
 .hestia-title{
}
```

I have tried

```html
.hestia-title{
  font-size: 0px;
  background-image:url(assets/img/quick_test.jpg);
}
```

This makes it look like this:

[image]

Could anyone point me in the right direction with this please? Thanks

I have now been able to get it looking like this:
[image]

Using this code:

```html
.page-id-88 .page-header .hestia-title{
  color:transparent;
  background-image: url(assets/img/title_mock.png);
}
 .page-header.header-small .hestia-title{
  background-size:contain; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
 .home .hestia-title{
  display:none;
}
```

This is the page.php content

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts and attachments.
 *
 * @package Hestia
 * @since Hestia 1.0
 */

get_header();

do_action( 'hestia_before_single_page_wrapper' );

?>
<div class="<?php echo hestia_layout(); ?>">
 <?php
 $class_to_add = '';
 if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && ! is_cart() ) {
  $class_to_add = 'blog-post-wrapper';
 }
 ?>
 <div class="blog-post <?php esc_attr( $class_to_add ); ?>">
  <div class="container">
   <?php
   if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) :
     the_post();
     get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );
    endwhile;
   else :
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
   endif;
   ?>
  </div>
 </div>
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Try with `color: transparent`

Comment: Thanks, when i added .page-header .hestia-title{color:transparent;} That made the text disappear! The image seems to be stretched to a certain size though. Is that something to do with margins?

Comment: The image adapts to the size of your box so if you want a specific size you must give size to the box (`with ` and `heght`) and `background-size: cover` and `background-repeat: no-repeat`. If you want the image to look complete at any size you must put it `background-size: contain` and `background-repeat: no-repeat`

Comment: note : replacing the text will be bad for your SEO if you don't also remove the <h> tag and put it somewhere else. - else, if you just want the text to be a background of the text - you can create a metabox with an image selector and use that in your php. This can be done via ACF (advanced custom fields) or by creating it yourself - this way you can have a specific image om specific pages.

Comment: a `<h>` tag with fon't size 0, or display none etc. will also be punished by google

Comment: Oh no! I didn't realise that @Stender . Is using display:none; bad for SEO in any case or just when customising titles?

Comment: just know, that a `display:none` on a `<h>` tag, which is what is googles primary indicator for what the page is about, can in worst case scenario lead to a ban from google searches.  - display none in itself is not bad for SEO, but trying to hack your page rank with tons of keywords that are hidden <h> tags is dangerous. - also there is no need to worry - Just only have 1 `<h1>` tag and don't hide it.

Comment: There is a section about it here : https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-ruin-google-rank-1616463

Comment: Thanks @Narcorga, the background-size:contain and and background-repeat:no-repeat are working well but the image is off centre.

Comment: @Stender ahh okay, thanks. I think that i am using the image in the place of the text and it's still under the <h1> tag when i right click and inspect.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the page.php file of your active child theme find out `<? the_title(); ?>` function. You can commnet this code then page title will not come.
For the image, you can use the featured image, set featured image on each page. Now you can use this code to display image

```
if (has_post_thumbnail()) { 
the_post_thumbnail('full');            // just the image        
}
```

To hide page title from CSS use this code

```
.page h1.hestia-title {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Prakash Singh,
Thank you for the reply. My child theme contains front-page.php, functions.php and style.css. I have only edited the style.css so far. Is it too late to create these pages now or is there a way to do this with only the CSS. Thanks

Comment: I have edited my post to show the current state of my issue. Thanks

Comment: You can copy page.php from parent theme to your active child theme.

Comment: Hi @Prakash Singh, do i need to add anything when i copy it to the child theme or do i just copy the whole thing over as it is? Thanks

Comment: just find the page.php file copy from parent theme and paste it into the child theme folder after that change it as I have mentioned above.

Comment: There is no title within the page.php from what i understand. I have posted the page.php code in my question now.

Comment: I checked your page.php file and also downloaded the free version of Hestia theme. I can see if you set page featured image in each page it would display as the banner as you have mentioned.  For hiding the page title I can see they are using the hook to display page title that is in class-hestia-header-layout-manager.php file.

Comment: Hi @Prakash Singh, i'm using the child theme, Tiny-Hestia but only the style.css has changed. I have tried setting the title images as featured images but they don't show anywhere. Thanks for helping.